# Call being rejected because extensions not found in context

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to make a call using custom files, since im not allowed to edit the main asterisk .conf files

sip.conf has:

```
#include "sip_custom.conf"
#include "extensions_custom.conf"
```

On the sip_custom.conf i have two trunks:

```
[study-sip] - My main login ( Registered on Zoiper )
[provider] - The provider trunk
```

Login uses the context 'dial-custom' that is configured in extensions_custom.conf

On extensions_custom.conf the context dial-custom is configured as:

```
[dial-custom]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/provider/${EXTEN:1},60)
exten => _X.,n,NoOp(HANGUPCAUSE is ${HANGUPCAUSE})
exten => _X.,n,NoOp( Dial Status: ${DIALSTATUS})
exten => _X.,n,Goto(hang)
exten => _X.,n(hang),NoOp(Hanging...)
exten => _X.,n,HANGUP()
```

The call should go to the trunk [provider] when i dial using the context [dial-custom] but instead i get the error message:

Call from 'study-sip' (xxx.xxx.xxx.9:xxxxx) to extension '5541xxxxxxxx' rejected because extension not found in context 'dial-custom'.

If i use the original Asterisk .conf files ( sip.conf and extensions.conf ) it works... But when i use the ones i included with #include, it does'nt.

If i type: 'dialplan show' and hit tab, the contexts in extensions_custom.conf does'nt even appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) reload asterisk

if not works

2) stop asterisk, start it in console mode with verbosity on

```
asterisk -rx "stop now"
asterisk -vvvvgc
```

3) check in log if/why it not load your file.

Comment: "Call from 'study-sip' (xxx.xxx.xxx.9:xxxxx) to extension '5541xxxxxxxx' rejected because extension not found in context 'dial-custom'."

This is the only message i get

Comment: Check log while it loading

Comment: Just checked and gaveme the same error. No worries tho. I gave up using custom files and now im just using the original ones. But thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set From Number extension

**context=dial-custom**

```
[XXXXXXXX]
canreinvite=no
context=dial-custom
host=192.168.1.1
qualify=yes
type=friend
```

example if your **from-number =98989**
then same example would be like given below

```
    [98989]
    canreinvite=no
    **context=dial-custom**
    host=X.X.X.X:XXXX
    qualify=yes
    type=friend
```